# Hover setting for all elements

Tags: html, css

How to set up hover effect for all elements with only one declaration?

Example:

```
#element1: hover, #element2:hover, #element3:hover, #element4:hover {
background: color
}
```

I want to say :hover only one time.

How to use a shorter way?

Answer (score 0):

You could instead just give a class to all of the elements that you want to have the hover effect.

After that, you would only need one css call:

```
.myHoverClass:hover {
  /* My code here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*:hover { color: red; }
```

> An Asterisk (*) is the universal selector for CSS. It matches a single
>   element of any type. Omitting the asterisk with simple selectors has
>   the same effect. For instance, *.warning and .warning are considered
>   equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can but it's not recommended as it can lead to some odd cascade or specificity issues.

Use the **universal selector**

```
*:hover  {
your styles here
}
```